# Can a colon follow dependent clause?

Tags: punctuation

Two fires burning opposite each other: one that is kindled to acknowledge god’s grandeur and the other one that reminds us how insignificant everything else in life is; a subtle reminder of the dichotomy of life.

Here, can a dependent clause “Two fires burning opposite each other” be followed by a colon? If not, what punctuation mark should I use? 
Please correct.

Comment: Unless used in the context of a list, where this is just one of the list items, or something being used for stylistic effect (neither of which seems obvious here), you shouldn't be using just a dependant clause in the first place. Regardless of punctuation or anything that follows it, providing only a dependent clause is ungrammatical. There is no punctuation that can save it.

Comment: Normally Depends come after the colon.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's used in the context of a list, where your phrase is just one of the list items, or it's used for stylistic effect (neither of which seems obvious here), you shouldn't be using just a dependant clause in the first place.

Regardless of punctuation or anything that follows it, providing only a dependent clause is ungrammatical. There is no punctuation that can save it.

---

But you could reverse the sentence structure you have so that it's actually an *independent* clause followed by a colon, making it grammatical:

> A subtle reminder of the dichotomy of life is two fires burning opposite each other: one that is kindled to acknowledge God’s grandeur and the other to remind us how insignificant everything else in life is.

Note that I also made a few minor edits to address some unrelated issues.

Answer (score 0):

Context and authorial tone is important here. Your sentence is not a sentence yet--there's no main clause or verb that holds it all together. Grammar. However, your sentence is poetic and sounds good.

If you're writing poetry, you're fine. Go with colon, it's fine too--colons have lots of strict definitions, and less strict common usage.

If you are writing a novel and you don't mind using nonstandard constructions sometimes, go for it. It's experimental, it's a bit weird, etc? There are many non-standard uses of fragments that are accepted in fiction.

If this is in a non-fiction article, a dissertation on a religious ceremony, etc., then you've got to rewrite your sentence so it has a main clause.

Here is a simple way to fix that part of your sentence--remove the "ing":

```
Two fires burn**<strike>ing</strike>** opposite each other: one that is kindled to acknowledge god’s grandeur**,** and <strike>the other</strike> one that reminds us how insignificant everything else in life is; a subtle reminder of the dichotomy of life.
```

Someone else will have to chime in on that semicolon. I think it also needs a clause--it's just a noun right now, and it's not a continuation of the list.